# how to get the response time in micro/nano seconds in IBM-RPT (Performance Testing Tool)

Tags: performance-testing, rational-performance-test

I am working in Socket protocol. I am getting the response time as Zero for a few transactions even if the transactions are getting passed(checked in backend as data is created in DB). So I want to change the settings in IBM-RPT to get the response time in micro/nano seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the VMARG -DrptNanoTime. You can find some details in the PDF [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27022226&aid=1).

Also, FYI, you'd get faster responses if you post your queries on the RPT forum on IBM DeveloperWorks site [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000326).